# PHP perform an action after specific time

Tags: php, time, cron

I have had this problem for a pretty long time. I want to do *something* after some specific time from a PHP script; for instance, let's say a user registers on my website, but unless he clicks on the provided activation link, the account will be removed in 45 mins. How do I accomplish this? I have thought of writing a PHP guard script which would check the database for any expired entries and then delete any, and setting up a cron for, say, every 3 mins. Is that the way to go?

Comment: yes, that's the way to go.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it

Comment: Seriously, 3 upvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think of every such problem as having to *execute code* at that specific time when something is "supposed to happen". I'm putting "supposed to happen" in quotes because something doesn't have *to happen*. If you consider accounts not activated for 45 minutes as invalid, then this can be perfectly expressed by logic without *doing* anything specific after exactly 45 minutes. Wherever you check for valid not-yet-activated accounts, you can make a check *"is not active and has been created within last 45 minutes"*. If the account doesn't satisfy both conditions, it's not valid.

You can still use a cron job to clean out stale data at your leisure, but this can happen once a day or so. It doesn't have to be *exactly 45 minutes after*.